# Static array variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can I create an static variable as array in javascript, What I want to do is to keep the value static even when refreshing the page.

I'm trying now is create a function as object like:

```
function Data(p){
    Data.point.push(p);
    Data.size++;
}
Data.size = 0; 
Data.point = [];
```

But then I noticed every time I refresh the page, it will reset the Data because of the last two lines.

Comment: If you are refreshing the page, but you want it to maintain what you did **BEFORE** page refresh, a cookie is in order.

Comment: In order to keep something "static," you would either have to make use of cookies, [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), sessions, or a database.

Comment: There is no state in javascript when used in browsers, and as such no "static" variables that keep their value across page reloads.

Comment: Even though keeping it in session or cookie the value get reset..  better change the order of the execution `Data.size = 0; 
Data.point = []; Data("oops"); function Data(p){
    Data.point.push(p);
    Data.size++;
}
`

Comment: Persistent storage in browsers is a bit all over the place, but getting better. It might be easier for you to use a library that hides the ugliness: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No javascript data is preserved from one page load to the next.  The entire javascript context of a page is destroyed when a new page is loaded over the top of it.

Your options for saving state that survives a page load are as follows:

1. Save the data in [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) so future web pages can read it from there.
2. Save the data in a cookie so future web pages can read it from there.
3. Save the data on your server so it can be loaded into future pages automatically or so future web pages can query the server with ajax.
4. Encode the data into a queryString and use that URL when reloading the page, then parsing the data out of the queryString when the new page loads.

Of all of these, the LocalStorage option is probably the simplest and cleanest.  You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage

LocalStorage (or session storage if you want a shorter lifetime for the storage) is available in IE8 and above and all other popular browsers.  The MDN article referenced above even includes a shim that will fallback to cookies if LocalStorage is not supported (e.g. old versions of IE).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) to keep data across page refreshes.